# Como criar uma funcao em javascript igual o que o graphql faz, filtrando retorno por query object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma funcao parecido com o funcionamento do graphql.

criei uma variavel simulando o retorno de uma api que lista seus veiculos:

```
const veiculos = {
    "bicicletas": null,
    "carros": [{
      "pecas": ["volante", "roda", "etc"],
        "documentos": [{
          "ipva": "em dia",
          "documentoDeBlindagem": true,
          "seguro": {
            "dataDoContrato": "2020-0-01",
            "pagamento": "em dia"
          },
        }]
    }]
}
```

no meu frontend envio via body, uma query que vai definir o retorno da minha requisicao.

exemplo 1 - buscando bicicletas:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bicicletas": "*"
  }
}
```

o retorno da minha chamada ficaria entao:

```
{ bicicletas: null }
```

exemplo 2 - buscando carros e bicicletas:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bicicletas": "*"
    "carros": "*"
  }
}

ou

{
  "query": "*"
}
```

o retorno da minha chamada nesse caso seria tudo que tem no obj carros:

```
{ 
  "bicicletas": null,
  "carros": [{
      "pecas": ["volante", "roda", "etc"],
        "documentos": [{
          "ipva": "em dia",
          "documentoDeBlindagem": true,
          "seguro": {
            "dataDoContrato": "2020-0-01",
            "pagamento": "em dia"
          },
        }]
    }]
}
```

esta parte funciona bem, segue abaixo como fiz:

```js
var veiculos = {
    "bicicletas": null,
    "carros": [
        {
        "pecas": ["volante", "roda", "etc"],
      "documentos": [
        {
            "ipva": "em dia",
          "documentoDeBlindagem": true,
          "seguro": {
              "dataDoContrato": "2020-0-01",
              "pagamento": "em dia"
          },
        }
      ]
    }  
  ]
}

const graphql = (query, data) => {
    let retorno = {};

  if(query === "*"){
    return data;
  }
  
  
  Object.values(query).map((v, i) => {
    const prop = Object.keys(query)[i];    
    if(v === "*"){    
      retorno[prop] = data[prop];
    } else {
            // eu acho que fazer novamente o que foi feito se encaixaria para resolver isso (recursividade)   
    }
  });
  
  return retorno;     
}

const queryEx1A = {
    bicicletas: "*"
}
const queryEx1B = {
    carros: "*"
}
const queryEx2A = {
    bicicletas: "*",
  carros: "*",  
}
const queryEx2B = "*"

console.log("queryEx1A", graphql(queryEx1A, veiculos));
console.log("queryEx1B", graphql(queryEx1B, veiculos));
console.log("queryEx2A", graphql(queryEx2A, veiculos));
console.log("queryEx2B", graphql(queryEx2B, veiculos));
```

porem creio que para solucionar casos em que a query venha com mais niveis ex:

```
const queryEx3 = {      
    carros: {
      documentos: { seguro: "*" },
    },  
}
```

podemos resolver com recursividade mas nao sei como implementar no meu codigo

Comment: como melhorar minha pergunta?

Comment: Você não está fazendo uma pergunta, e sim pedindo ajuda de implementação. Mude a pergunta de: "Como fazer esse código" para: "Como resolver o problema X do algorítmo, que está sendo usado para solucionar este código", e deixe claro qual é o passo que está dando erro e qual o erro exato.

Answer (score -2):

```
import { ERROR_DATA_CANNOT_BE_FILTERED } from './errorMessage';

/**
 * Filters the provided data object or array based on the specified query object.
 * If the query is "*", the entire data object or array is returned.
 *
 * @param data - The data object or array to filter.
 * @param query - The query object that specifies the properties to include in the filtered result.
 */
export function bffFilter(data: any, query: any): any {
  // Validate the data to ensure it can be filtered.
  if (validateData(data)) {
    return { message: ERROR_DATA_CANNOT_BE_FILTERED, data };
  }

  // If the query is "*", return the entire data object or array.
  if (query === '*') {
    return data;
  }

  // Check if the data is an array or an object
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    // If the data is an array, create a new array to store the filtered items
    const filteredArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // Define the properties to include in the response for each item in the array
      const itemResponse = {};
      defineProperties(data[i], itemResponse, query);
      filteredArray.push(itemResponse);
    }
    return filteredArray;
  } else {
    // If the data is an object, create a new object to store the filtered properties
    const filteredObject = {};
    defineProperties(data, filteredObject, query);
    return filteredObject;
  }
}

/**
 * Defines the properties to include in the response based on the query object.
 *
 * @param obj - The object to define properties for.
 * @param response - The response object to add the defined properties to.
 */
function defineProperties(obj: any, response: any, query: any): void {
  // Get the keys of the query object
  const keys = Object.keys(query);

  // Iterate over the keys of the query object
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const prop = keys[i];
    const value = query[prop];

    // If the value is "*", include the entire property in the response.
    if (value === '*') {
      response[prop] = obj[prop];
    } else {
      // Otherwise, recursively filter the property using the specified query.
      response[prop] = bffFilter(obj[prop], value);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Validates the provided data to ensure it can be filtered.
 *
 * @param data - The data to validate.
 * @returns True if the data is invalid, false otherwise.
 */
function validateData(data: any): boolean {
  return (
    data === null ||
    data === undefined ||
    typeof data !== 'object' ||
    (Array.isArray(data) && data.length <= 0)
  );
}
```